# Updating Template String with Loop in Typescript

Tags: typescript

So say I have a function like

```
private createStack(levelName: string, usernames: Array<string> ){
     const sampleStack = 
     new   pipelineStackName(
      id: `${levelName}-${username}`
     )
}
```

Where `pipelineStackName` is a constructor in another file--

Basically, I'd like to iterate through the list of usernames and generate a new `id` for each username. I tried a `forEach` loop within the string template itself but I believe that failed because `forEach` returns an undefined object? In any case; what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `const sampleStacks = usernames.map((username) => new pipelineStackName({ id: \`${levelName}-${username}\` }))`?

Comment: What should ````createStack```` return?